# Iterate through groups of rows which have a unique col value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Take for example this code:

```
for col in df:
    print(df[col].unique())
```

It will print each unique string/value under `col`, rather than every single row in the df. This is sort of what I want, but not really.

What I'd like to do is iteratively take all the rows associated with the first unique `col` value, execute some code on them, and then move on to the second unique `col` value and do the same, until I've exhausted each batch of unique values. How can I do that? I guess the easiest way to communicate what I want is imagine you could do:

```
for col.unique() in df:
        #do some processing here
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by:

```
for col in df:
    for x in df[col].unique():
        print(df.loc[df[col].eq(x), col])
```